# how do I keep a menubar app on osx "alive" on the lock screen?

Tags: macos, menubar, launchd

The title is the question. But i'll elaborate. I am building a menubar app for OSX and I need the app to be running while the mac is sleeping or at the very least while the lock screen is showing. I have looked into solutions around the web like `launchd` and the `KeepAlive` key but as far as I understand those are only for `deamons` and can't be used for regular apps. I can't find anything else about this issue... I will appreciate any help at all.

Thanks

Comment: What is your goal exactly? While the Mac sleeps, no app is active! In lock screen probably no user is active, and thus no apps can run.

Comment: Ok then maybe while the user is about to login...

Comment: After the user is logged in, but how to determine when's user is about to login.... ?

Answer (score 0):

Add your application to login item.

```
tell application "Finder" to set myAppPath to POSIX path of (application file id "com.company.app” as string)

tell application "System Events"
 if (login item "yourappname" exists) is false then make new login item at end of login items with properties {path: myAppPath, hidden:true, kind:application, name:"yourappname"}
end tell
```